# Learn to use Scilab and ImageJ

Tags: imagej, scilab

I am trying to learn to use Scilab and ImageJ, which is software that uses computer coding commands to make graphs and spreadsheets, etc. I've never learned how to code, could you direct me to any websites/classes/online tutorials that would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason to use ImageJ?

Scilab provides a lot of native plotting functionality and for specific image processing operations you can extend Scilab with a toolbox like [SIVP](http://sivp.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: It is used in an internship I am applying for. Do u know of any tutorials for Scilab?

Comment: When I started, I used the [tutorial pages](http://wiki.scilab.org/Tutorials) and you learn a lot just by doing it. If you are in need of challenges, have a look at [project euler](http://projecteuler.net/problems).